# Customize table output Jupyter Notebook VS code

Tags: numpy, visual-studio-code

I have problems visualising tables created with Numpy on VS code:

[image: table]

As you can see the contrast is very poor. Any suggestion on how to tune its appearance?

Answer (score 2):

This should accomplish what you're looking for, but might not be the most elegant solution:

1. *File > Preferences > Settings* (or use shortcut `Ctrl+,` on Windows)
2. Paste `@ext:ms-python.python data science ignore vscode theme` into the search box
3. Toggle *Ignore Vscode Theme* checkbox to *ON*
4. Restart VS Code

The contrast issue will hopefully be fixed by VS Code now using a light theme for all Jupyter Notebooks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! For now, it is a good solution. Let's hope for a fix!